# Circular Reference Alternative

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

### **Background:**

Currently, I am trying to create two Task Operators. A SettingOperator class and a MessageOperator class. Below I provided a background as to what I am trying to achieve with both classes.

**Purpose of my SettingOperator** - Creates player preferences such as a normal desktop application and stores them to a file in the data folder. These preferences can be updated via player commands, configuration files, etc.

**Purpose of my MessageOperator** - Handles logging localized messages and configures the plugins current locale (as long as it is currently supported by the plugin otherwise defaults to English).

### **Problem:**

Currently, I am initializing both operators as such on the onEnable() Method

```
private static PluginName instance;
private SettingOperator setting;
private MessageOperator message;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
 
    // TASK OPERATORS
    setting = new SettingOperator(this);
    message = new MessageOperator(this);
}

/* CLASS INSTANCES */

@Contract (pure = true)
public static AdminConsole getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static SettingOperator getSettingOP() {
    return setting;
}

public static MessageOperator getMessageOP() {
    return message;
}
```

Then I am trying to call the references to both classes because both use each other interchangeably.

```
*** These Classes Are Into Separate Files, but for the sake of easy readability, I put them in one code block ***

public class SettingOperator {
    private final MessageOperator message = PluginName.getMessageOP();
}

public class MessageOperator {
    private final SettingOperator message = PluginName.getSettingOP();
}
```

### **Question:**

Is there a better way of doing this, because I tend to catch an overflow exception and does not tell me what kind of problem it is causing? Any help is appreciated and would love some constructive criticism.

Comment: *both use each other interchangeably* - what you mean? give an example.

Comment: You mean they're _coupled_, as far as technical terms. In my case, I would simply pass the main class reference and refer to `PluginName#getSettingsOp` when I needed it. Then I'm not having to store various fields all over the place. That said, Messaging and Settings are fairly unidirectional; they can be created without having to call on other code pieces too much at all. However, if you're configuring message output or debug logging settings changes, these kinds of interop are okay imo

Comment: @Rogue I will give it a shot and thanks for the term correction

Answer (score 0):

Use event listener.

Here is the idea.

```
public interface PropertyChangeListener {
    void onPropertyChanged(Object source, String propertyName, String propertyValue);
}

public class SettingOperator implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private PropertyChangeListener listener;

    public void setPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onPropertyChanged(Object source, String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
        if(!Objects.equal(getProperty(key), value)) {
            setProperty(key, value);
        }
    }

    public void setSetting(String key, String value){
        properties.setProperty(key, value);
        listener.onPropertyChanged(this, key, value);
    }
}

public class MessageOperator implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private PropertyChangeListener listener;

    public void setPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onPropertyChanged(Object source, String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
        consoleLog("Property Set)";
    }

    public void setLocale(String key, String value){
        listener.onPropertyChanged(this, key, value);
    }
}


public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
    // TASK OPERATORS
    setting = new SettingOperator(this);
    message = new MessageOperator(this);
    setting.setPropertyChangeListener(message);
    message.setPropertyChangeListener(setting);
}
```

You can extends the method `onPropertyChanged` and use some bean as event instead of String. Also you can extend it and add to class no a single listener, but multiple. But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code example is that when SettingOperator is instantiated, it calls `PluginName.getMessageOP()` before MessageOperator has been instantiated, so the call returns null and SettingOperator never gets a reference to MessageOperator.

Instead of making it so SettingOperator and MessageOperator both try to get a reference to each other immediately which isn't possible, you could make it so each one only needs a reference to the main plugin class to start with, and they fetch a reference to the other Operator from the main plugin instance only when necessary.

Here's an example with the problem fixed. In the example, you can see SettingOperator make use of a MessageOperator method. (MessageOperator could also make use of SettingOperator in the same way.)

```java
public class PluginFoo extends JavaPlugin {
    private SettingOperator setting;
    private MessageOperator message;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        setting = new SettingOperator(this);
        message = new MessageOperator(this);
    }

    public SettingOperator getSettingOP() {
        return setting;
    }

    public MessageOperator getMessageOP() {
        return message;
    }
}

public class SettingOperator {
    private final PluginFoo plugin;
    public SettingOperator(PluginFoo plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin
    }
    public featureA() {
        System.out.println("SettingOperator featureA");
        plugin.getMessageOP().helperForFeatureA();
    }
}

public class MessageOperator {
    private final PluginFoo plugin;
    public MessageOperator(PluginFoo plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    public helperForFeatureA() {
        System.out.println("MessageOperator helperForFeatureA");
    }
}
```